# Закомитил лишние файлы на gitlab, каким образом их можно снести с репозитория, не затрагивая локальные?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, commit

Закомитил лишних файлов, помогите разобраться. Закинул полностью весь проект, со всем вытекающим.

Comment: .gitignore тогда забыл настроить. Если его сейчас настроить, поможет ли это?

Comment: Если речь идет только про локальный репозиторий, то используйте `git reset --soft HEAD~`. Эта команда переместит указатель HEAD на предыдущий коммит, но оставит рабочую директорию без изменений. Так же сохранит индексирование файлов. Далее вам останется только отменить индексацию ненужный файлов и да добавить .gitignore файл, чтобы больше такого не происходило. Подробней про `reset` [тут](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Инструменты-Git-Раскрытие-тайн-reset). Так можете добавить файл .gitignore, выполнить команду `git commit --amend`, которая изменит последний коммит. На сайте выше все написано)